# SKAction how to combine withKey and completion

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I´m quite new to iOS and Sprite Kit programming and wonder how to combine:

```
-[SKAction runAction:withKey:]
```

and

```
-[SKAction runAction:completion:]
```

On the one side, I want to prevent a node from running the same action (or action sequence) again, on the other, I want to react to the termination of an action, but there is no method and, as far as I see, no way to use both at the same time.

Thx

Comment: you can use an action sequence where you add a runBlock action at the end that will act as the completion block

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `+runBlock:` action in `+sequence:` like this:

```
SKAction *yourAction = ...

SKAction *completion = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    // Your code.
}];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ yourAction, completion ]];

[node runAction:sequence withKey:yourKey];
```

If you use this multiple times, create `SKNode` category with such method:

```
- (void)runAction:(SKAction *)action withKey:(NSString *)key completion:(void(^)(void))block;
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a nice solution for **Swift 2.x** (update to **Swift 3.x** here below..) created by Daniel L. Alves, using `SKNode` extension:

```
extension SKNode
{
    func runAction( action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion: dispatch_block_t? )
    {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock( completion )
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            runAction( compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            runAction( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }
}
```

### Update to Swift 3.x

```
extension SKNode
{
    func run(action: SKAction!, withKey: String!, optionalCompletion:((Void) -> Void)?) {
        if let completion = optionalCompletion
        {
            let completionAction = SKAction.run(completion)
            let compositeAction = SKAction.sequence([ action, completionAction ])
            run(compositeAction, withKey: withKey )
        }
        else
        {
            run( action, withKey: withKey )
        }
    }

    func actionForKeyIsRunning(key: String) -> Bool {
        return self.action(forKey: key) != nil ? true : false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to react to the *termination of an action*, yes you need to use `SKAction runAction:(SKAction*) completion ^{ "Your special code here" }`. This will execute your special code on the termination of the action.

When you use the `SKAction runAction:(SKAction*) withKey:(NSString*)`, if your action already have a key, you can retrieve the action.
If an action using the same key is **already running**, it is **removed** before the new action is added.